# Gradle Espresso package not recognized

Tags: android, android-espresso

i can not import the espresso package

this is my app gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
signingConfigs {
    config {
        keyAlias 'XXXXX'
        keyPassword 'XXXXX'
        storeFile file('XXXX')
        storePassword 'XXXX'
    }
}
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'my.package.name'
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
}
productFlavors {
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
}


dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile project(':customlib1')
compile project(':customlib2')

compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.3'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2'
```

}

i just clean and rebuild my project and update libraries, but when i try to use in my Test

```
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.LargeTest;

import com.estratek.postreet.postreet_lib.activities.About;

import static java.util.regex.Pattern.matches;

@LargeTest
public class EspressoTest extends  ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<About> {

public EspressoTest() {
    super(About.class);
}

@Override
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    getActivity();
}

public void testListGoesOverTheFold() {
    onView(withText("Hello world!")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
}
```

}

this line give me error, and i can't import the not found functions:

> onView(withText("Hello world!")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Manually invoking the gradle task sometimes helps as well. Try running `./gradlew assembleAndroidTest` from the terminal.

Comment: Yes, i tried to do it. I was very interesed to use Espresso, but it's kind of hard to configure. I think i will use roboelectric  y Robotium

Answer (score 0):

Check if you added correct maven repositories in repositories section. Such mavenCentral() mavenLocal()

Comment: yes, i have that repositories, and jcenter() too, however it is not resolving dependencies